# Is there anything similar to "KO.mapping.fromJS" in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to attach some new calculated property to a complex json object returned from a REST Service. This can be easily achieved through KnockoutJS's Mapping pluggin.

But I have decided to go for AngularJS this time. Is there any modules/pluggins similar to knockout's mapping pluggin ??

my **PROBLEM** is as shown below:

JSON Returned from server is something like:

```
{
id:2,
name: 'jhon',
relatives:[
            {id:1,name:'linda', score:{A:10,B:33,C:78} },
            {id:2,name:'joseph', score:{A:20,B:53,C:68} },
            {id:3, name:'keith', score:{A:40,B:83,C:30} }
          ]
}
```

in the above json object, I want to attach some calculated property to each objects inside "relatives" collection based on the score each relative has.

Comment: there is no inbuilt functionality but you could use you could use foreach loop and create a property dynamically

Comment: that's frustrating! it means that each time we add new relative we should create this "property" as well. after using knockoutjs it seems very ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
angular.extend($scope, data);
```

I'm also starting to use Angular, coming from Knockout and Durandal :) Hope this might work for you. The data should be accessible in your view ($scope) directly.

Edit: See this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/AXJ3q99H1Hc).

Answer (score 1):

Basically in angular there is no thing similar to Observable variables.

AngularJS makes observing separately from $scope itself.
To make map from Json in AngularJS you can use [**angular.fromJson**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) to bind data from Json.

To add fields to your scope you also can use [**angular.extend**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend).

But anyway adding calculated field is thing that you need to make by yourself, for this purpose you can try to use watch methods: [**$scope.watch**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), [**$scope.watchGroup**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup),
 [**watchCollection**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection).